# How can I handle InvalidSignatureException while validating JWT in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing my own Spring Boot authentication server and resource server, and they work normally.
The authentication server provides RS256 JWS token and the resource server is able to verify the token.

I was so happy and I would like to know what would happen if I use a different RSA key pair to verify the JWS token. It came out:

```
org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.InvalidSignatureException: RSA Signature did not match content
    at org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.RsaVerifier.verify(RsaVerifier.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.jwt.JwtImpl.verifySignature(JwtHelper.java:287)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.jwk.JwkVerifyingJwtAccessTokenConverter.decode(JwkVerifyingJwtAccessTokenConverter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore.convertAccessToken(JwtTokenStore.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore.readAccessToken(JwtTokenStore.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.jwk.JwkTokenStore.readAccessToken(JwkTokenStore.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.loadAuthentication(DefaultTokenServices.java:229)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5a1f25c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$14463cf2.loadAuthentication(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
...
```

and the response is <500 Internal Server Error> with body:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        h2 {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        h3 {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
        }

        b {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
        }

        p {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
            background: white;
            color: black;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        a {
            color: black;
        }

        a.name {
            color: black;
        }

        .line {
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #525D76;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

**I would like to handle this error into custom JSON error body, or at least look like the same as the normal AuthenticationException**

e.g. <401 Unauthorized>

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Invalid JWT/JWS: RSA Signature did not match content"
}
```

My Spring / Boot dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt")
    ...
}
```

What I have tried:

- Handle in `@ControllerAdvice` (From other answers in Stackoverflow, should be the request still haven't passed into MVC, so useless)
- Register custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` through `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity)` (Don't know why it can't help, but tried)
- **Edit**
  Tried the suggestion from @Jazzepi, Implementing `HandlerExceptionResolver` or extending `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver` with method:

```
@Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof InvalidSignatureException) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(new MappingJackson2JsonView());
            mav.addObject("key", "value");
            return mav;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And then tried to register through `WebMvcConfigurator.extendHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandleExceptionResolvers>)` (It can't help, still output the same response as above)

---

**Edit:**

**How I build and decode the token?**
Follows exactly this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-jws-jwk

**How to re-play this situation?**

1. Start both auth and resource server.
2. Get a token from auth server and use the token in the resource server once to make the resource server cache the public key in local
3. Change the keystore file in the auth server and restart
4. Get a new token from the restarted auth server
5. Use the new token in the resource server

Comment: please add the code on how you are building and decoding your tokens

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already updated the question.

Comment: Did you figure it out ? Im having the same situation and the exceptionHandler is handling it as RuntimeException with status 500 :(

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot comes with a couple of classes that map exceptions to methods to run when those exceptions are thrown.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers-java.util.List-

Registers a HandlerExceptionResolverComposite with this chain of exception resolvers:

> ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver for handling exceptions through
>   ExceptionHandler methods.
>
> ResponseStatusExceptionResolver for exceptions annotated with
>   ResponseStatus.
>
> DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver for resolving known Spring exception
>   types

I think you want to create your own exception handler. It will give you a chance to run whatever code you want in response to your specific exception. Probably want to implement this interface. Checkout the docs though because Spring provides a rich variety of abstract classes that you can extend that will make your life easier instead of writing from the interface from scratch.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html

Finally you need to register your handler with Spring. This looks like a good way to do it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#extendHandlerExceptionResolvers-java.util.List-

Good luck!

To troubleshoot I would set a breakpoint in 
`org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java` on the doResolveException and see if it's catching and handling your exception there (I think it is).

There's an order amongst these resolvers in Spring. You probably want to give yours the highest order so that it gets a chance to handle the exception before the default one.

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)

You also probably want your handler to use `response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.getMessage());` sendError instead of mucking around with the ModelAndView() stuff. That's for telling spring which webpage to redirect to. Look at the default handler individual methods to get an idea about different ways you can handle errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it seems not working, please refer to the edited question

Comment: @user2602850 edited with some advice on troubleshooting